# Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: null

Tags: java, cordova

I am trying to generate .apk file for my angular application.

To generate apk used - 
`cordova build android`

after some process it generate error.

I have also set user variables and system variables
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
  JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271
     PATH = ...;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin;
         C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;
         C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

echo %JAVA_HOME% is printing => C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271
java -version => java version "1.8.0_271"
       Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
       Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)
gradle -v => Gradle 5.6.3
cordova -v => 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
cordova platform version android => Installed platforms:
                 android 9.0.0

Android Studio installed => 4.0.0

my error is

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: null
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables
```

Answer (score 1):

New versions have some issues so after downgrading gradle and android version, I have restarted my system and again folowing this steps worked for me-
https://medium.com/@christof.thalmann/convert-angular-project-to-android-apk-in-10-steps-c49e2fddd29

as I was trying to create apk for angular app.

Comment: How did you do the downgrade? Experiencing the same issue...

Comment: cordova platform add android@8.1.0  =>  Downgrade project android version, Android studio 4.0.0 install => https://android-studio.en.uptodown.com/windows/download/2252916, gradle 5.6.3 => https://gradle.org/releases/